# Account verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have account and company Page, and 2 months back Facebook asked for account verification and we have submitted the details already for the verification. But still it is pending (more than 3 months).

Kindly help me how to contact Facebook to activate our company Page and give us access to our panel.

If the rule has been changed to update the Facebook profile in Personal profile (Currently it as Company profile ), we will update it as personal, even for that also we need account access.

Answer (score 0):

There is no set time on how long a verification request can take, only Facebook can tell.

After submitting you must have receive a message (in support inbox), or any mail, try to look into that if there is a way (or link) to reach them.

I am assuming you already have 50+ likes on your page.

https://www.facebook.com/business/resources/